# Same properties but different class name - XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Is it possible to have common class to consume this XML? Both are API response from different routes

```
<Employee>
 <FirstName>...</FirstName>
 <LastName>...</LastName>
 <Age>...</Age>
 <DOB>...</DOB>
</Employee>
```

---

```
<Customer>
 <FirstName>...</FirstName>
 <LastName>...</LastName>
 <Age>...</Age>
 <DOB>...</DOB>
</Customer>
```

I am looking for something like

```
[XMLAlias="Employee","Customer"]
public class User
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName{ get; set; }
 public int Age{ get; set; }
 public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
}
```

Or atleast

```
[XMLAlias="Employee"]
public class Customer
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName{ get; set; }
 public int Age{ get; set; }
 public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And you know which XML is in the response? Or not?

Comment: @Joehl Yes, I know the route call

Comment: Ok. So I would do this as descriped in the answer from @Set below

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have separate Employee and Customer classes, derived from base User class with common properties.

In future you can meet a situation, when one of the xml/class will have additional specific fields. So:

```
public class User
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName{ get; set; }
 public int Age{ get; set; }
 public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
}

public class Employee : User
{
}

public class Customer : User
{
}
```

Comment: I agree... the problem is with XML Response as both XMLs should have the same root they missed that during api development